# Is it possible to convert the return type of collect (Collectors.ToList() to LinkedList?

Tags: java, stream

I want to write a function that will create a stream of random numbers:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class fillRandom {
    public static List<Integer> IntFill(){
        return  new Random().ints(10,0,100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

And then I want to return it to my LinkedList:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Print printer = new printImpl();
        linkedList = (LinkedList) fillRandom.IntFill();
        printer.print(linkedList);

    }

}
```

But I get an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.LinkedList`

Is it possible to do something to make it work without  `collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))` ? If I don't want to return exactly the ArrayList from Random

Comment: Why don't you want to use `toCollection`? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Sweeper Well, I just think that it would be better not to depend on one implementation ,but to assign the one that I have (LinkedList or ArrayList)

Comment: `List<Integer> list = fillRandom.IntFill(); List<Integer> lL = new LinkedList<>(list);`

Comment: Why do you want a `LinkedList`? It is almost always the wrong choice, both in terms of performance and in terms of memory overhead.

Comment: You mention "assign the one that I have", however you are assigning it to a List. You're declaring it as `List linkedlist` and not as `LinkedList linkedlist`. the first LinkedList you create with `new LinkedList<Integer>()`is completely discarded and garbage collected as soon as you assign it the new one in `linkedList = (LinkedList) fillRandom.IntFill()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), there is no guarantee on the type of list returned, and it specifically asks you to use `toCollection`

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.

If your reason for not using `toCollection` is simply to avoid using a specific implementation in `intFill`, and wants to allow the caller to specify what `List` they want, you can alway give the user that option with a `Supplier` parameter, just like how `toCollection` does.

```
public static <C extends Collection<Integer>> C intFill(Supplier<C> collectionSupplier){
    return new Random().ints(10,0,100).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(collectionSupplier));
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Integer> linkedList = fillRandom.intFill(LinkedList::new);
```

Alternatively, rather than casting, use the `LinkedList` constructor to create a `LinkedList` from whatever `List` is returned by the `toList` collector.

```
List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>(fillRandom.intFill());
```

Note that a disadvantage of this is that it will loop over the whole list again, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to using the interface `List` instead of using an implementing class as `LinkedList`.

Having said that, if you really want to collect to the class of an object you already have, you can do something like this by first letting the Collector know what object you want to base on (I don't recommend it though):

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class fillRandom {
    public static List<Integer> IntFill(List base){
        return (List<Integer>) new Random().ints(10,0,100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> {
            try {
                return base.getClass().newInstance();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Default
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

And then call it as such:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Print printer = new printImpl();
        linkedList = fillRandom.IntFill(linkedList);
        printer.print(linkedList);

    }
}
```

Also note that when you do a collect, you are creating a completely new List, you are not filling the one you already made. Then when you assign it to the variable you are replacing the old one.

Answer (score -4):

```
    List linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list = (LinkedList)fillRandom.IntFill();
    linkedList = new LinkedList<>(list);
    System.out.println(linkedList);
```

This code should work for you